# How to concatonate using getElementbyID on a list item element?

Tags: javascript, html, concatenation

here's the code

```
    <h1>Timeworn Kumbhiraskin Maps</h1>

    <label for="room">What chamber did you reach?</label>

    <select id="room">

        <option value="none">No portal</option>
        <option value="first">First Chamber</option>
        <option value="second">Second Chamber</option>
        <option value="third">Third Chamber</option>
        <option value="fourth">Fourth Chamber</option>
        <option value="fifth">Final Chamber</option>

    </select>
    

    <ul id="percentages">
        <li id="np">No portal: </li>
        <li id="firstC">First Chamber: </li>
        <li id="secondC">Second Chamber: </li>
        <li id="thirdC">Third Chamber: </li>
        <li id="fourthC">Fourth Chamber:</li>
        <li id="fifthC">Final Chamber: </li>

    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

```
var totalMaps = 0;
var pPortal = 0;
var pFirst = 0;
var pSecond = 0;
var pThird = 0;
var pFourth = 0;
var pFifth = 0;

window.onload = function(){

    document.getElementById("np").value += string(pPortal);
    document.getElementById("firstC").value += string(pFirst);
    document.getElementById("secondC").value += string(pSecond);
    document.getElementById("thirdC").value += string(pThird);
    document.getElementById("fourthC").value += string(pFourth);
    document.getElementById("fifthC").value += string(pFifth);
}
```

Basically I'm just having trouble with the javascript. I want to display the javascript variables in the list, but it's not showing. Any help? Am I doing something wrong? I've tried a few different methods and looked online but it doesn't seem like anyone has the answer I'm looking for

Comment: List items have no value property

Comment: Use `innerHTML`, not `value`. Or [`insertAdjacentText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentText).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a variable to a string you have to you the `String()` function (case sensitive). Also you missed the part saying innerHTML. This is working for me

```
<body>
    
    <ul id="percentages">
        <li id="np">No portal: </li>
        <li id="firstC">First Chamber: </li>
        <li id="secondC">Second Chamber: </li>
        <li id="thirdC">Third Chamber: </li>
        <li id="fourthC">Fourth Chamber:</li>
        <li id="fifthC">Final Chamber: </li>

    </ul>
    
</body>
<style>
    body {padding: 0.5rem 1rem;}
</style>
<script>
let totalMaps = 0;
let pPortal = 0;
let pFirst = 0;
let pSecond = 0;
let pThird = 0;
let pFourth = 0;
let pFifth = 0;

window.onload = function(){

    document.getElementById("np").innerHTML += String(pPortal);
    document.getElementById("firstC").innerHTML += String(pFirst);
    document.getElementById("secondC").innerHTML += String(pSecond);
    document.getElementById("thirdC").innerHTML += String(pThird);
    document.getElementById("fourthC").innerHTML += String(pFourth);
    document.getElementById("fifthC").innerHTML += String(pFifth);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
document.getElementById('np').innerHTML += pPortal;
```

...etc
JS + operator automatically casts your number type to string in this case.